# How to apply combine technique with if condition

Tags: c#, coding-style, code-cleanup

C# code syntax is bellow

```
        public void Cancel()
        {

            // If reservation already started throw exception
            if (DateTime.Now > From)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("It's too late to cancel.");
            }
//for gold customer IsCanceled= false
            if (IsGoldCustomer() && LessThan(24))
            {
                IsCanceled = false;
            }
//for not gold customer IsCanceled= true
            if (!IsGoldCustomer() &&LessThan(48))
            {

                IsCanceled = true;
            }

        }

        private bool IsGoldCustomer()
        {
            return Customer.LoyaltyPoints > 100;
        }

        private bool LessThan(int maxHours)
        {
            return (From - DateTime.Now).TotalHours < maxHours;
        }
```

Comment described business logics, want to combine  if (IsGoldCustomer() && LessThan(24)) and  if (!IsGoldCustomer() &&LessThan(48)) condition. Is there any suggestion how to ?

Modified both if condition bellow,but modification not satisfy my requirement.

```
//for gold customer IsCanceled= false
            IsCanceled = !(IsGoldCustomer() && LessThan(24));
//for not gold customer IsCanceled= true
            IsCanceled = !IsGoldCustomer() &&LessThan(48);
```

Comment: Looks like something that should be refactored into a `CanCancel` function that returns a Boolean value. A `Cancel` function probably shouldn't fail under unexceptional conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IsCancelled = IsGoldCustomer()? !LessThan( 24 ) : !LessThan( 48 );
```

or even:

```
IsCancelled = !LessThan( IsGoldCustomer()? 24 : 48 );
```